# Why does total spin conservation law forbid the spin wave gap in Heisenberg magnets?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, symmetry, quantum-spin, symmetry-breaking

What is the explanation for total spin conservation forbidding the spin wave gap in Heisenberg magnets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Total spin conservation" means global $SU(2)$ spin-rotation symmetry (a *continuous symmetry*) of the Heisenberg model, and "spin wave" indicates an *ordered* ground state that *spontaneously* breaks the spin-rotation symmetry.

Thus, according to [Goldstone theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_boson), there must be a **gapless** mode for spin wave.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for jabber. How about taking Dyzaloshinskii-Moriya interaction or any other anisotropicity into account? Invalidate Goldstone theorem?

Comment: @huotuichang Yes. "Goldstone theorem" is about the **spontaneous** symmetry breaking. If we add some spin-rotation symmetry broken terms(anisotropicity) to the Heisenberg model, then the symmetry is **explicitly** broken at the Hamiltonian level and there would be no **spontaneous** symmetry breaking, thus we **can not use** the "Goldstone theorem" in this case.